Value of CustomInput not visible in POST-request
I'm trying to build a custom form type in Symfony which is based on a web component. For simplicity I built a custom input component.
This component seems to work when I use it in an HTML form - demo. However when used in Symfony, the value doesn't appear in the POST-request
export class CustomInput extends HTMLElement {
    static formAssociated = true;

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['value', 'name'];
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.internals = this.attachInternals();
        this.render();
    }

    get inputElement() {
        return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input');
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.inputElement.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
            this.value = event.target.value;
        });
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (name === 'value' && oldValue !== newValue) {
            this.value = newValue || '';
        }
    }

    get value() {
        return this.inputElement.value;
    }

    set value(newValue) {
        this.inputElement.value = newValue;
        this.internals.setFormValue(newValue);
    }

    render() {
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <input type="text" />
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define('p-input', CustomInput);



In the Symfony context I also added a custom form type:
final class CustomInputType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}

The corresponding Twig for the form type:
{%- block custom_input_widget -%}
    <p-input type="text" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}></p-input>
{%- endblock custom_input_widget -%}

The form itself is using the new form type:
final class TestForm extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
       $builder->add('title', CustomInputType::class, [
            'label' => 'test.title',
        ]);
       // other fields
    }
}

And finally the twig to render the form:
<div class="form">
    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id':'test_edit_form' }}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    
   <div class="element">
        <div class="label">{{ form_label(form.title) }}</div>
        <div class="input">{{ form_widget(form.title) }}</div>
    </div>

    {# more form elements #}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>

The twig file is registered in the twig.yaml under form_themes.
The component gets rendered when using my new custom form type and it also sets the value correctly if the underlying data object is prefilled. The custom element gets a name attribute like all other form elements.
<form name="test_form" method="post" action="/test/edit" id="test_edit_form">
        <div class="element">
            <div class="label"><label for="test_form_title" class="required">Title</label></div>
            <div class="input"><p-input id="test_form_title" name="test_form[title]" required="required" value="Test"></p-input></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="element">
            <div class="label"><label for="test_form_number" class="required">Number</label></div>
            <div class="input">    
                <select id="test_form_number" name="test_form[number]" required="required">
                <option disabled="disabled" value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ... -->
</form>

But when I submit the form, the value is missing completely in the POST-Request. I can see all the other submitted values of the native input elements but the one of my custom element is missing.
Can someone help me figuring out what I'm missing?

Can you also provide how you rendering the full form with your CustomElement? "The custom element gets a name attribute like all other form elements" - This is not visible in the snippet currently posted, I'm assuming this is generated with {{ block('widget_attributes') }} - So maybe a rendered version of the form could be good to add in as well

Sure thing, I updated my post with more details. Hope this helps.

I tested your snippets on my own and it worked as expected: the custom input was included in the form payload and sent to the backend. It might be something else.
